# PHP Convert Arabic Text to Image

Tags: php, arabic

I got problem from my text to image(jpg) function for arabic text.
I tried below code, it only working for normal text.
But when I tried to input the text with Arabic text, the display will show  [image]

```
mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$text = "ديفيد";

$font_file      = 'coolvetica.ttf';
$font_size      = 8 ; // font size in pts
$font_color     = '#000' ;
$image_file     = 'assets/img/Soccer.Field_Transparant.png';

$x_finalpos     = 127;
$y_finalpos     = 103;

$mime_type          = 'image/png' ;
$extension          = '.png' ;
$s_end_buffer_size  = 4096 ;
```

I already tried to check the code but no find the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: they font file you use will have to support the characters.

Comment: So, what is the font type that support normal text and arabic text?

Comment: ask google, ther are millions of font files

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell, the coolvetica.ttf font doesn't normally support arabic letters, so if you're enforcing that font, that's most likely the cause. You'll probably need to switch to one of these fonts instead:

http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Arabic.html